# multi-threaded prime generator

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, primes

I'm currently working on this multi-threaded prime number generator which calculates the number of prime numbers in a range between 2 - N, at the moment every thread calculates all prime numbers and it looks like the threads are running one after another but I want that all threads run simultaneously.

Now I want to ask how to tell a thread that it should only calculate a slicesize, not all prime numbers and that "t" threads run simultaneously.

For example: 2-1000 with four threads -> every thread should calculate 250 numbers

Thanks in advance!

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* compile: gcc prime.c -lpthread -o prime */
/* execute: ./prime -N 1000 -t 8 */

pthread_mutex_t aktuell_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


int N;
int Primzahlen;

int aktuell = 2;
int t;
//int slicesize = N/t;


void print_usage(void)
{
    printf("Usage: prime -N <value> -t <value>\n");
}

void *prime(void *a)
    {

    int Laufvariable;

    int i;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&aktuell_lock);
    for (i = 0; i < N/t; i++) {

    for (aktuell; aktuell <= N; aktuell++) {

    for (Laufvariable = (aktuell-1); aktuell % Laufvariable; Laufvariable--) {
    }

    if (Laufvariable == 1)
        Primzahlen++;
    }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&aktuell_lock);
        return NULL;
    }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timespec start, finish;
    double elapsed;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    int s;
    int option;

    while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "N:t:")) != -1)
        switch (option) {
        case 'N':
            N = atoi(optarg);
                break;
        case 't':
            t = atoi(optarg);
                break;
        default:
            print_usage();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    pthread_t threads[t];

    for (s = 0; s < t; s++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, prime, NULL);
    }

    void *result;

    for (s = 0; s < t; s++) {
        pthread_join(threads[t], &result);
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);

    elapsed = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
    elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;

    printf("\nCount Primes [1 .. %d] - TaskCnt: %d - Slicesize: %d\n", N, t, N / t);
    printf("Threads: %d\n", t);
    printf("limit: %d\n", N);
    printf("Total Prime Count: %d\n", Primzahlen);
    printf("Runtime: %f seconds\n\n", elapsed);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with using threads, is that the quickest method is to test division only by the prime numbers you have already proved. That way one thread will be quicker than 4 which test every (odd) divisor.

Comment: you should provide some sample code to show how you manage your threads

Comment: pass different range as function parameters to each pthreat  and discard  mutex.  You need rewrite  pthread  function

Comment: Now you have posted some code, it is doing far more work than it needs to. Check for even number, then check odd divisors from `3...+=2` up the the square root of the number. Better yet, just check the primes you already found as divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Using locks for parallel processing is definitely not in the way to a scalable program.

Instead of accumulating result and state in global variables under the lock, try accumulate partial thread-specific results and then merge them.

There is ready-to-use example of scalable prime-number counter which resides in [tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb)  [distribution](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/download#stable-releases). You can use it directly or take the idea of work range partitioning and reducing of partial results and implement it in plain `C` if it is your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in phases. The simplest version of this uses a single thread to generate an array of primes until prime(i) * prime(i) >= N. Set R = N-prime(i), which is the range of numbers to test. Then thread[j] (j starts with 0) should test from prime(i)+j * (R/t) to prime(i)+(j+1) * (R/t), and the last thread tests from prime(i)+j * (R/t) to N (t is the number of threads). Each thread generates it's own count, and once all threads complete, the counts are summed.

Each thread could also generate it's own range of prime numbers, and once all threads are done, the arrays are concatenated. This could be extended to go through several passes, Like find primes from 2 to 100, use threads to find primes from 100 to 1000, concatenate arrays, find primes from 1000 to 1000000, ... .